# Why the remote branches are not shown in the ".git\refs\remotes\origin\" folder?

Tags: git

In my test github repo, all my remote branches are shown in the `.git\refs\remotes\origin\` folder. Like this:

[image]

But I just checked another non-toy repo, all the remote branches cannot be seen in that folder. Like this:

[image]

But the `git remote show origin` does show a lot of remote branches. And I still can create new local branch to track those remote branches.

Why?

Comment: Try a `git fetch` then check your remotes again

Comment: @CoryKramer Just tried. Still nothing. I just cloned it. Do I really need to fetch again?

Comment: Is there a file $GIT_DIR/packed-refs? It might be the references are packed using git-pack-refs. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs

Comment: @Wazner Yes. There's a `.git\packed-refs` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git has a feature where it will pack the seperate ref files into a single file to improve performance and lower the storage cost. When a ref is packed, it will no longer exist as a seperate file in the `refs`  folder.

> When a ref is missing from the traditional $GIT_DIR/refs directory hierarchy, it is looked up in this file and used if found.

You can pack the ref files using the [`git pack-refs` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs).

Comment: There also seems to be a longer-term project for "plugin" control for where reference information is stored. Presumably this is so that sites like GitHub, that wind up with far too many active references, can start storing them in a real database.  One's best bet is to stick with documented interfaces, such as the `git rev-parse` command for getting values, and `git update-ref` for setting them.